# Cannot write to or read data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to get firebase to work on one of my university projects. I followed the documentation provided by Google and set up everything accordingly.

**build.gradle prj**

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    
}
```

**build.gradle app**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

..........

  dependencies {
      //noinspection GradleCompatible
      implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')

      //implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.0"
      implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
      implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
      implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
      implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
      implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
      implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.3'
      implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.3'
      implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
      testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
      androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
      androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Here is my the code that I use to access Firebase, it is in an *Object SportModel*

```
object SportModel: Observable() {

private var mValueDataListener: ValueEventListener
private var sportList: ArrayList<Sport>? = ArrayList()

private fun getDatabaseRef():DatabaseReference{
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("sports")
}


init{
    if(mValueDataListener != null){
        getDatabaseRef()?.removeEventListener(mValueDataListener!!)
    }
    Log.i("SportModel","data init 24 line")

    mValueDataListener = object:ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                Log.i("SportModel", "data updated line 27")
                val data: ArrayList<Sport> = ArrayList()
                if(snapshot != null){
                    for(snapshot:DataSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                        try{
                            data.add(Sport(snapshot))
                        }
                        catch(e:Exception){
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            Log.i("SportModel", "37, failed to insert into the list")
                        }
                    }
                    sportList = data
                    Log.i("SportModel", "Data updated, there are ${sportList!!.size} entrees in the cache")
                    setChanged()
                    notifyObservers()
                }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            if(error != null){
                Log.i("SportModel", "Data update canceled")

            }
        }
    }
   getDatabaseRef().addValueEventListener(mValueDataListener as ValueEventListener)
}
fun getData(): ArrayList<Sport>? {
    return sportList
  }
}
```

I create SportModel in the OnCreateView method of a fragment.
**MainFragment.kt**

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    
    //Instantiate SportModel
    SportModel
    SportModel.addObserver(this)
    currActivity = requireActivity()
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    
    //create an empty data array
    val data:ArrayList<Sport> = ArrayList()
    adapter = SportAdapter(view.context,R.layout.sport_item, data)
    val listView:ListView = view.findViewById(R.id.sport_list)
    listView.adapter = adapter

    //ADDED IN ORDER TO TEST IF FIREBASE WORKS AT ALL
    var ref:DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    ref.setValue("data123")
    var mValueDataListener = object:ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            Log.i("SportModel", "WORKS")
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            if(error != null){
                Log.i("SportModel", "Data update canceled")
            }
        }
    }
    ref.addValueEventListener(mValueDataListener)

    return view
}
```

And I also have an overridden *update* method in the same Fragment

```
override fun update(o: Observable?, arg: Any?) {
    adapter?.clear()
    val data = SportModel.getData()
    if(data!= null){
        adapter?.clear()
        adapter?.addAll(data)
        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

From my understanding, the onDataChange function of the ValueEventListener fires on initialization or when data changes(duhhh). For some reason, even in the simple test code, I wrote, this function doesn't get used. I tried writing to firebase as well. When I do that the onDataChange function is invoked in both my test code and the actual code (This should mean that the data changes???), but no actual data is added to firebase and no data is extracted from it.

I tried setting up firebase from two different accounts but to the same effect.

Maybe I am missing something really simple?

If you need more code just let me know!

Comment: Is any of the error Log statements printing something in the logcat?

Comment: No error, nothing.